# Nested 'if' or something else in Perl

Tags: perl, if-statement

I struck in a simple nested *if* statement.

The requirement is as below.

```
if (Condition1) {
    if (Condition2) {
        print "All OK";
    }
    else {
        print "Condition1 is true but condition2 not";
    }
    else {print "Condition1 not true";
}
```

Is it possible to write this code in Perl or is there another short or better way to fulfil this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *if condition 1* is true. The clause is missing its closing `}` which should be inserted right before the last *else*.

Try to line things up this way:

```
if (...) {
    if (...) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
else {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) à la [ternary operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator):

```
print $condition1
      ? $condition2
        ? "All OK\n"
        : "Condition 1 true, Condition 2 false\n"
      :   "Condition 1 false\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *given..when* if your version of Perl >= 5.10.

```
use v5.14;

my $condition1 = 'true';
my $condition2 = 'True';

given($condition1) {
    when (/^true$/) {
        given($condition2) {
            when (/^True$/) { say "condition 2 is True"; }
            default         { say "condition 2 is not True"; }
        }
    }
    default { say "condition 1 is not true"; }
}
```

Comment: err, you *can*, but why would you want to?  that code is so much more work to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if (Condition1=false) {
     print "Condition1 not true";
}
elsif (Condition2=True ) {
    print "All OK"; 
}
else {
    print "Condition1 is true but condition2 not";  
}
```

Comment: While this is correct, it is non-intuitive and a little hard to maintain

Comment: Agreed. Howewer the OP asked for a shorter or better solution, and this is shorter:).

Comment: Bad Perl. Would not pass strict check for "false" and "True".  Wrong operator as using assignment = when needs comparison ==.  Much better never to compare to a true/false value.  Better to use the scalar itself for if true, and !scalar for if false.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Condition1) {
  print "Condition1 not true";
}
else {
  if (Condition2) {
    print "All OK";
  }
  else {
    print "Condition1 is true but condition2 not";
  }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: Fixed the code. Also hopefully now clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
#OR condition
if ( ($file =~ /string/) || ($file =~ /string/) ){
}

#AND condition
if ( ($file =~ /string/) && ($file =~ /string/) ){
}
```